# is_numeric does not work when reading from txt file?

Tags: php

In a text file I have a file like this:

```
Olivia
7

Sophia
8

Abigail
9

Elizabeth
10

Chloe
11

Samantha
12
```

I want to print out all the name only and ignore the numbers.

For some reason, it dont work - it wouldn't print anything?

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("names.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  if (!is_numeric((int)$line_of_text)) { 
    echo $line_of_text;
    echo "<br />";
  }
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: uhm... you always cast to int so it's always numeric and true therefore so your condition will never be fullfilled. Remove the (int). Maybe you want to use a regex instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are casting every line with `(int)`. So even lines that are *strings* will become `0` (zero).

You can change your code to:

```
!is_numeric($line_of_text)
```

**Note:** [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) will return `true` for decimals and scientific notation also. If you are strictly determining if the line contains *digits*, I suggest [ctype_digit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

#### UPDATE

You will also need to `trim($line_of_text)` as [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) includes the newline.

Code inside `while()`:

```
  $line_of_text = trim(fgets($file_handle));
  if (!ctype_digit($line_of_text)) { 
    echo $line_of_text;
    echo "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: I have remove the (int), it show everything including number?

Answer (score 5):

```
!is_numeric((int)$line_of_text)
```

Think about it: You're casting the line to an `int`, so whatever it was before, it'll become a number. Then you're testing whether it's *not* numeric. Of course it'll be numeric, because you made it so. Hence the condition will always be false.

Stop casting to `int` before testing for `is_numeric`.